Web-scraping in R using rvest::session with no "submit"
I need to download pdf documents from this website: https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/PDFViewer.asp. My code below selects the year from the first dropdown menu, which populates school districts in the third dropdown menu, and then selects the school district. After filling out these two field, a button called "view" appears that links to the pdf document, but I don't know how to click on the "view" button:
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

session <- html_session("https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/PDFViewer.asp")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
years <- form$fields[[6]]$options[-1]
years <- years[grep("201[6-9]|202[0-3]", years)]

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
    form <- set_values(form, 'YearSelected' = years[i])
    session <- submit_form(session, form)
    form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
    districts <- form$fields[[8]]$options[-1]

  for (j in 1:length(districts)) {
        form <- set_values(form, "DNSelected" = districts[j])
        session <- submit_form(session, form)

    # [ I filled out the form; how do I download the file? ]**
  }
}


There are a couple of issues here. First of all, not every district has a record for every year, so your code needs to be able to handle a search with no results. Secondly, there are 1,293 districts and 9 years, so you will need to send over 11,000 requests to the server. Even with a fast PC, this is likely to take several hours.
Working out how to get the pdfs requires reading the JavaScript code on the page to see how the page construct the pdfs' URL. It is probably best to store the URLs so you can download them at your leisure.
session <- session("https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/PDFViewer.asp")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
years <- c(na.omit(as.numeric(form$fields$YearSelected$options)))
years <- years[years >= 2016]
pdf_urls <- character()

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  form <- set_values(form, 'YearSelected' = years[i])
  session <- session_submit(session, form)
  form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
  districts <- form$fields$CDSelected$options[-1]
  district_nm <- form$fields$DNSelected$options[-1]
  
for (j in 1:length(districts)) {
    form <- set_values(form, "CDSelected" = districts[j],
                       DNSelected = district_nm[j])
    session <- session_submit(session, form)
    pdf_link <- session$response |> 
      read_html() |> 
      html_element(xpath = "//input[@type = 'button']")
    if(length(pdf_link) > 0) {
      pdf_urls <- c(pdf_urls, paste0(
        "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/",
        "showPDF.asp?pdpath=", pdf_link |> html_attr("name"),
        '&pdname=',
        sub("^.*'(.*\\.pdf)'.*$", "\\1", pdf_link |> html_attr("onclick"))))
    }
  }
}

The first few urls are:
head(pdf_urls)
# [1] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDF\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDFNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001902a7.pdf"
# [2] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDG\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDGNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001903a7.pdf"
# [3] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDH\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDHNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001904a7.pdf"
# [4] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDJ\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDJNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001906a7.pdf"
# [5] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDK\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDKNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001907a7.pdf"
# [6] "https://tealprod.tea.state.tx.us/Audit/Public/showPDF.asp?pdpath=Q412\\FDEJ\\DDEMDL\\sv0n0pvny\\DDEMDLNEFDEJ.cQS&pdname=001908a7.pdf"

Then you can do, for example
download.file(pdf_urls[1], "first.pdf")

The first url links to a document with this front page:

